# return value of the dataset where the other variable meets condition in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "my_data" and I am trying to return the name of the restaurant that has the highest rating.

What is the function I can apply? I tried this:`"my_data$Name(which(max(my_data$rating)))"`
It did not work.

Thank you

```
>  Name         city rating
1    a     new york    4.5
2    b   new jersey    3.0
3    c rohde island    5.0
4    d          xyz    2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to get the position index of the `max` value and then the corresponding 'Name' can be extracted based on that.

```
 my_data$Name[which.max(my_data$rating)]
 #[1] "c"
```

In the OP's code, there are a couple of mistakes.

1. `which(max(` - The `max` returns the maximum value.  `which` would be used to return the numeric position based on a logical index. i.e. `which(mydata$rating == max(mydata$rating)` will return the position.
2. `my_data$Name(` - If the first case was correct, then we only need to subset it.  For that, we use square (`[`) brackets.  Usually, the `(` is used for function calls i.e. `mean(x)`, `max(x)` etc..